# jquery datatable ajax propery

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to populate jquery data table from web service using ajax property of data table, so I can still do client side processing.

I am thinking something like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( 
{ "ajax": { "url": "../.NET webservice", "type": "POST" } } );
```

If I can then I need to return data from .NET web service as an array of array ?

**e.g.**

```
{ "data": [ [ "Tom", "Utah", "Koala", "Kite"],

["Bob", "New Mexico", "Kangaroo", "Kite"] ] }
```

Can you please confirm ?  I do not see any good examples that show how to do this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following ways for server data

```
$("#example").dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource" : "../.NET",
    "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
         aoData.push({
                    "name" : "param1",
                    "value" : val1
                }, {
                    "name" : "param2",
                    "value" : val2
                });
         $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function(json) {
                        fnCallback(json)
                    });
                }
});
```

Or you can use:-

```
$("#example").dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource" : "../.NET?param1=value&pram2=value2"
});
```

only point is response should be in json from server.

Comment: I get loading... message now in datatable but nothing gets loaded. var table = new DataTable(); table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.LoadDataRow(new object[] {"Kshipra", "Kanpur", "Koala", "Kite"}, true);Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);  this is .NET code .  and calling above code on button click. I now get loading... message. I do not know the reason. Need a way to debug.  web service is hosted locally for testing.

Comment: html code: var sbSourceTable = new StringBuilder();
            sbSourceTable.Append("<table id='example' style='width:100%' class='display' cellspacing=0>");
            sbSourceTable.Append("<thead><th>Name</th><th>Place</th><th>Animal</th><th>Thing</th></thead>");

            divDataDisplay.InnerHtml = sbSourceTable.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Calling ajax like this is possible.

```
$('#example').dataTable( { "ajax": { "url": "../.NET webservice", "type": "POST" } } );
```

However datatable is capable of reading data from any json, so it depends on you in which form you want your service to return the data. You just need to handle the data as per your service is sending. The best possible way is to send an array of objects.

Comment: I have set a breakpoint in web service to return data, it is not hitting the method I am calling. So I have no way of knowing why data is not getting rendered. Any debugging advice ?

Answer (score 0):

I use a function, passed as "ajax" dataTable option:

```
function getData(data, callback, settings) {
    // settings contain info about data start index, number of records to request, sorting options, etc...
    //settings._iDisplayLength, settings._iDisplayStart

    // got some data into arrayOfData (via ajax request)
    callback({ data: arrayOfData, recordsTotal: totalRecordsCount, recordsFiltered: totalRecordsCount });
}
var dataTableOptions = {
    // some column settings
    // and ajax settings:
    processing = true;
    serverSide = true;
    ajax = getData;
}
$(dataTableTargetElement).dataTable(dataTableOptions);
```

Comment: this is server side processing. I was leaning more towards doing in built client side processing, so I do not have to worry sending parameters for paging to work properly. Any thoughts on this will help.

Comment: In the "getData" function I make an ajax request to my server with my options, and then I receive data, I pass them to the dataTable via "callback" function. Thus I have total control over all data obtaining process.